# Symfony 3: Many associations in one entity

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 associations in one entity

```
class User
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Employee")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $employee;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $client;
//....
}
```

When im trying generate relations in database I got nothing.  But with only one one association it is working. 
I'm using console command:

```
doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: What's the output of the command?

Comment: [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                                       
 An index with name 'uniq_8d93d649bf396750' was already defined on table 'user'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with different names for join columns.

```
class User
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Employee")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $employee;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $client;

    //...
}
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#association-mapping-defaults

Comment: You just created something like this https://i.imgsafe.org/0c753ea.png Is this good practice? I wanted connect id with (client) id and (employee) id. Like this: https://i.imgsafe.org/041556e.png

Comment: Yes, in general, that is good practice. The way you have it, its trying to do exactly the same thing but is leading to a name conflict. In theory you could do it the way you are showing in the picture but it will require a lot more manual labour and definitely not worth it. Take advantage of the doctrine magic.

Comment: Did you think that i should delete (main) id from user? User is just basic info about client,employee.Right now i get onetoone from client to user. I'm creating clients in client table and add basic info to user table. It is correct?

Comment: I would keep the main id.  Without knowing much about your app, if a user can be a client and an employee at the same time then this is a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to Akash what you want isnt really possible how you have laid it out without some work. The easiest way to accomplish it is with an extra column on your other 2 tables.

```
class User
{    

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Employee", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $employee;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Client", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $client;

    //...
}

class Employee
{    

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="employee")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    //...
}

class Client
{    

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    //...
}
```

For reference take a look at the docs for more info on [bidirectional associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional)